# How can i get Y position in all the website page

Tags: javascript, dom, position

I have a website which is 6 viewports height.
I would like to get the Y position for no matter where  i am in the page not only the viewport.
I have tried :

- event.pageY ;
- element.getBoundingClientRect();
- window.innerHeight / outerheight;

It doesn't solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try offsetHeight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Alexei Petrenko but it calculates an element position.
But I fix my problem with "window.scrollY" that take the number of pixel from the top.